# Firefox addon - read incoming xhr response

Tags: firefox-addon

is it possible to read incoming xhr response from a specific web address with a Firefox addon?
When it is possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you sent the request, you just have to assign a callback function.  in this example, processResponse would receive the results.

```
function processResponse(xhr){
  console.log("\nRESPONSE of " + xhr.responseText.length + " characters.\n");
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        processResponse(xhr);
    }
}   
xhr.open ("post", "myphp.php", true);
var somePostData = "&command=print";
xhr.send (somePostData);
```